# How to listen on a particular collection

Tags: java, spring-data, arangodb

I am using Java driver to talk to ArangoDB service. In my use case, multiple clients write the data to ArangoDB. Is there any way that I can listen from other client, whenever there is a change happen on a collection

Comment: ArangoDB currently does not support it.

Comment: yaa, you are correct.. teste with Arango chair also, it is not working in cluster mode